# SSIS Flat File Destination Settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, bids, dts

I am running Data Flow Task (OLEDB source to Flat File Destination). Copying 36 columns data from SQL server to flat file with defined length for each field.

For first column i have defined column width as 5 (String), but actual value in 4 character and 5th Character should be NULL in the Flat file.

In database actual Date column value is "2012-01-31 00:00:00.000" , but i want to read only first 16 digits and write to flat file.

Please suggest how to do this.

I am not sure, what settings to be done to get data as shown in the below image.

[image]

Regards,
VHK

Comment: For the date field, you should output the data formatted with a CONVERT statement and other string manipulation. So, if what you need is YYYYMMDDHHNNSSms, that will take a couple of commands: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MyDate, 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), MyDate, 114), ':', '') as MyFormattedDate.

Comment: A NULL (I am assuming a CHAR(0) for file purposes) is, broadly speaking, problematic in a textual file, but you can always do a SELECT LEFT(MyValue + CHAR(0), 5) as MyPaddedValue.